# Best way to declare javascript constants

Tags: javascript

I am a java developer and working java script project after long time. I am surprised to see how much it changed in recent years and good to see it's getting standardized. I have a basic question,  in the current project I am seeing constants are declared using  prototype (project using ES5) and in some cases it's using getter to declare constant. So, what should be the best way to declare constants:

Using prototype: Some places it mentioned this is a bad way as we can override the Ooo.CONSTANT1 value.

```
function Ooo() {
}

Ooo.prototype.CONSTANT1 = 1;
Ooo.prototype.CONSTANT2 = 2;
```

The old way:

```
const CONSTANT1 = 1;
```

Using getter:

```
let _bar = {};
var Foo = function Foo() {}

Object.defineProperty(Foo, "bar", {
  get: function() {
    return _bar;
  }
});
```

Or some better way?

Comment: Putting it on the prototype doesn't make sense because it can unintuitively interfere with instances, but putting it on the constructor itself sounds like the best idea IMO. No need for a getter, just set `writable: false`. Try codereview instead.

Comment: Good idea. But if you use - use 'strict', it doesn't work. I am assuming you are saying something similar to this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: Sure, you're already using `Object.defineProperty`. Why wouldn't it work in strict mode?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create namespaced constants without dealing with the verbosity of getters while still getting similar results, you can try using Object.freeze. e.g.

```
const Directions = Object.freeze({
    NORTH: 0,
    EAST: 1,
    SOUTH: 2,
    WEST: 3,
});
```

Comment: Plus one for using Object.freeze

Answer (score 0):

You can try this syntax for all versions of `js`:

```
consts={};
 function DefAsConst(varName, val){
      Object.defineProperty(window.consts, varName, {
          value: val,  writable: false
      });
 }
 DefAsConst("const_1", 4);
 console.log(consts.const_1);
 consts.const_1=100;
 console.log(consts.const_1); //consts.const_1 is 4 still
```

Or try this version:

```
 consts={};
 consts.DefAsConst=function(varName, val){
    Object.defineProperty(this, varName, {
       value: val,  writable: false
   });
 };
 consts.DefAsConst("const_2", 40);
 console.log(consts.const_2);
 consts.const_2=100;
 console.log(consts.const_2);
```